# React: _this2.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm developing a voice controlled slide show (slides are iframes) using React.  I have a working version (it will loop over slides, voice commands for going to previous/next slide work ...) but when I try to add a command to pause the slide show loop, I get the error below.  My "next slide" command works and isn't really any different than the "pause loop" command, so I don't understand why the "pause loop" command is producing an error.

This is my first React app, any help would be much appreciated.

**Error:**

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _this2.setState is not a function

   | .then(res => res.json())
   | .then(
   |    (result) => {
>  |        this.setState({
   |            speechRecogStatus: result.speech_recog_status
   |        });
```

**Code:**

This is only part of the code and has been modified to remove irrelevant lines.

in App.js

```
import nextSlideCommand from './commands/next-slide';
import pauseLoopCommand from './commands/pause-loop';
import SlideList from './slide-list.json';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.fetchingMasterSwitchStatus = false;

        let initialSlideKeyword = SlideList.loop[0].keyword;

        this.state = {
            speechRecogStatus: "off",
            iframeSrc: SlideList.list[initialSlideKeyword].url,
            pageTitle: SlideList.list[initialSlideKeyword].title,
            loopIndex: 0,
            loopIsPlaying: true,
            iframeStyle: {visibility: 'hidden'},
        };

        if (annyang) {

            // define voice commands
            let commands = {
                'next slide': () => {
                    nextSlideCommand.call(this, SlideList);
                },
                'pause loop': () => {
                    pauseLoopCommand.call(this, SlideList);
                },
            };

            // Add our commands to annyang
            annyang.addCommands(commands);
        }

        // suggested by another StackOverflow post on 
        // this error - doesn't solve my problem
        this.getMasterSwitchStatus = this.getMasterSwitchStatus.bind(this);
        this.iframeOnLoad = this.iframeOnLoad.bind(this);
    }

    getMasterSwitchStatus() {

        // query an online JSON file periodically to determine whether this 
        // app should be listening for voice commands or not

        if (this.fetchingMasterSwitchStatus) return;

        this.fetchingMasterSwitchStatus = true;
        fetch("JSON_URL")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        speechRecogStatus: result.speech_recog_status
                    });

                    let status = (annyang.isListening()) ? "on" : "off";
                    if (status === result.speech_recog_status) {
                        this.fetchingMasterSwitchStatus = false;
                        return;
                    }

                    if (result.speech_recog_status === 'on') {
                        annyang.resume();
                    } else {
                        annyang.abort();
                    }
                    this.fetchingMasterSwitchStatus = false;
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.fetchingMasterSwitchStatus = false;
                }
            );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(
            () => {
                this.getMasterSwitchStatus();
            },
            CHECK_MASTERSWTICH_FREQ
        );
    }

    iframeOnLoad() {
        this.setState({
            iframeStyle: {visibility: 'visible'}
        });

        setTimeout(
            () => {
                if (!this.state.loopIsPlaying) return;
                utilFunctions.nextSlide(this, SlideList)
            },
            SlideList.loop[this.state.loopIndex].dwell * 1000
        );
    }

    render() {
        return [
            <div key="content" className="content">
                <Iframe key="iframe" src={this.state.iframeSrc} 
                        iframeStyle={this.state.iframeStyle}
                        onLoadFun={() => this.iframeOnLoad()}/>
            </div>
        ];
    }

}

export default App;
```

in `commands/pause-loop.js`

```
let pauseLoopCommand = function(SlideList) {
    this.setState = ({
        loopIsPlaying: false
    });
};

export default pauseLoopCommand;
```

in commands/next-slide.js

```
let nextSlideCommand = function(SlideList) {
    // calculate new loop index
    let index = context.state.loopIndex;
    index++;
    if (index > SlideList.loop.length - 1) {
        index = 0;
    }
    let keywords = SlideList.loop[index].keyword;

    // ok, change slide
    this.setState({
        loopIndex: index,
        iframeSrc: SlideList.list[keywords].url,
        pageTitle: SlideList.list[keywords].title,
        iframeStyle: {visibility: 'hidden'},
    });
};

export default nextSlideCommand;
```

Comment: Try to move `this.getMasterSwitchStatus = this.getMasterSwitchStatus.bind(this); this.iframeOnLoad = this.iframeOnLoad.bind(this);` to the constructor as see if the error disappears.

Comment: @Tholle - thanks!  Sorry, the code I had pasted into this post was incorrect and not representative of my actual code.  The lines you are referring to are actually in my constructor.

Comment: Ah, I see. That's alright. You are also overwriting `setState` with `this.setState = ({ loopIsPlaying: false });` in `pauseLoopCommand`. Try calling it as a function instead, like you have done in all other places.

Comment: oops, yeah, that's a problem.  OK, that seems to have fixed it.  Except, now when I try to move some of the code out the pauseLoopCommand() function to a utility functions.js file (I want to be able to use the pause functionality both in my voice command and possibly elsewhere in my code), I get a similar error message.  I'm using JavaScript's call method to bind this (i.e,  utilFunctions.pauseLoop.call(this, SlideList)), so I'm not sure why I'm running into this still.  Anyway, this is probably close enough - thanks!!!

Comment: @Tholle - feel free to add your comment as an Answer and I'll mark it as the answer that solved my problem.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Awesome! You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `pauseLoopCommand` function is assigning a new value to `this.setState`, so future `this.setState` calls will try to invoke this new object as a function, which will give rise to your error.

If you call it like a function like you do in all other places the error should disappear.

```
let pauseLoopCommand = function(SlideList) {
    this.setState({
        loopIsPlaying: false
    });
};

export default pauseLoopCommand;
```

Answer (score 1):

Per a comment from @Tholle, this was the offending line in my pauseLoopCommand() function:

```
this.setState = ({
    loopIsPlaying: false
});
```

This should have been:

```
this.setState({
    loopIsPlaying: false
});
```